# SQL Server performance improvement for select queries and aggregate function

Tags: performance, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I am using SQL Server Express edition and I have a table where 500~600 rows are being inserted every minute.

Table schema is something like this

```
ColumnName   DataType
CID          varchar(6)
PID          varchar(6)
DID          varchar(6)
MID          byte  
Date_Time    DateTime 
Col1         Decimal(19,6)     
Col2         Decimal(19,6)  
Col3         Decimal(19,6)        
.
.
Col32        Decimal(19,6)
```

Please be noted there is only insertion of new rows no updates and no deletes of existing rows is involved at any point of time. The table keeps growing at a huge rate (since I am using SQL Server Express edition, so it grows until the database size reaches 10 GB).

At the same time we fetch the table using select statement and some aggregate function on any column i.e. Col1,Col2.. Col32 with the filtration based on CID,PID,DID,MID,Date_time.

Currently the combined non clustered index is set as

```
 (CID, PID, DID, MID, Date_Time)
```

Let’s say if I do fetch `Col1` frequently and if I include the same in index, I get up to the mark improved performance. But I believe if I include all the 32 columns (`Col1, Col2.. Col32`) in the index it won’t be the good way.

My query patterns are as below where the difference between startdate and enddate can be of over 3 months, so I believe server has to consider the huge amount of data for returning the result set for below queries

```
Select top(1) 
from table 
where Date_time between <startdate> and <endate> 
  and CID = ‘@cid 
  and PID = ‘@pid’ 
  and DID = ‘@did’ 
  and MID = ‘@mdi’

Select top(1) Col1, Col2 
from table 
where Date_time between <startdate> and <endate> 
  and CID = ‘@cid 
  and PID = ‘@pid’ 
  and DID = ‘@did’ 
  and MID = ‘@mdi’ 
order by Date_Time desc

Select top(1) Col1, Col2 
from table 
where Date_time between <startdate> and <endate> 
  and CID = ‘@cid 
  and PID = ‘@pid’ 
  and DID = ‘@did’ 
  and MID = ‘@mdi’ 
order by Date_Time asc

Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 
from table 
where Date_time between <startdate> and <endate> 
  and CID = ‘@cid 
  and PID = ‘@pid’ 
  and DID = ‘@did’ 
  and MID = ‘@mdi’ 
order by Date_Time desc

Select Min(Col1), Max(Col2), Avg(Col3) 
 from table 
 where Date_time between <startdate> and <endate> 
   and CID = ‘@cid 
   and PID = ‘@pid’ 
   and DID = ‘@did’  
   and MID = ‘@mdi’
```

Now I have a task to make the performance improvement of such queries pattern and expecting to get the result set in 2~3 seconds at max.

I can make any modification in the table and can add any indexes as long as as its not hitting the insert operation.

Can anyone suggest me some inputs what should I do.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking the memory, CPU and disk IO during the query? If you request 3 months worth of row with 500 rows each second, 3 seconds seems to be very optimistic unless you have RAID SSD

Answer (score 0):

Since you're often sorting by `Date_Time` (rather than using `Date_Time` in the `WHERE` clause), I'd remove the `Date_Time` from your index and create a separate index just on `Date_Time`.

Also, since you seem to be retrieving `Col1` through `Col5` frequently, it might be a good idea to **include** those columns in your main index.

So I'd try this:

```
CREATE INDEX MainIndex
ON dbo.YourTable (CID, PID, DID, MID)
INCLUDE (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5)

CREATE INDEX DateIndex
ON dbo.YourTable (Date_Time)
```

So:

- **FIRST**, measure your current performance
- **THEN** make the changes
- Measure the performance again and see if there's any improvement - if yes, keep the new indexes, if not, go back to the original setup

Comment: col1 to col5 are not really frequently fetched it depends solely which column user have selected. so some time it may be only Col1 and some time any combination from col1 to col 32

Comment: @HarshalSam: **IF** you have a set of columns that are fetched more frequently than others, it *can be* beneficial to add those as *included columns* to the index. If you cannot determine any set that's more frequently used than others, then don't do it